# How to search for closed questions?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Is there any easy way to see a list of closed questions? Preferably with the ability to choose *which* close reason.

Perhaps this is possible by using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I've updated my answer - including the reply to the recent edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, `closed:1` as a search condition should bring up the list of closed questions. Add `migrated:0` for better result set.

[image: Searching for closed questions]

> Preferably with the ability to choose which close reason.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the search engine. If you have 10k & above, however, you can filter it from the [/tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=last2days) tab. but you're limited to a specific set.

[image: Tools - Closed questions]

> Perhaps this is possible by using the Data Explorer?

The data from Data explorer is typically a month or two out of date and even with the dated data, there's no way to group them into reasons why they were closed - a look at the schema indicates there's only record of it being closed, not why it was closed, so that's not an option

Comment: Only the review tab doesn't show closed questions.

Comment: @slhck you're right, updated